# How can I add changes in a Github library?

Tags: android, github

I'm new to using github and I download a rate dialog library for android app, but it doesn't allow users to modify buttons. so I've searched and found someone who provided these changes to the library but I don't know How to use it ?

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcmi3.png)

Comment: If the owner of the repo won't merge the changes, just clone it and merge in the branch with the changes you want.

Comment: thx bro , but I need more details cuz its the first time dealing with github libraries

Answer (score 1):

you can do it 2 ways

First,

1. clone the repo.
2. change it as you like
3. create a new repo of you own
4. push the project to new repo

Second,

1. fork the repo.
2. change it as you like
3. push the project to newly forked repo

Comment: thanks for your comment , as im new to github Im not familiar with these steps but I tried and did the first 3 steps now Im stuck in the fourth step :/